# RabbitMQ ha-mode all or exactly differences?

Tags: rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

We have a cluster with 3 nodes, we currently have the following HA (High Availability) mirror policy as shown below:

[image]

1. Seeing as we specify the **ha-params** as **2**, does this mean mirror to the 2 other nodes, or 2 nodes in total or the 3?
2. Is this the same as the following where we just specify **all**, as there are only 3 nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delving deeper and with a bit more understanding I can see that specifying **ha-params** as **2** will mean that a total of 2 nodes will be mirrored, so one of the nodes wont be! It's no the same as the **all** one, as that would mirror to all nodes, which would make more sense to me currently.

Answer (score 2):

A count value of **2** means **2 replicas**: 1 queue leader and 1 queue mirror. In other words: `NumberOfQueueMirrors = NumberOfNodes - 1`.

to dig more details: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html#mirroring-arguments